# Should you include units with no intra-unit variation in fixed-effects models?

Tags: regression, econometrics, causality, fixed-effects-model

Suppose I have a model such as

$$\text{logit(y)}_{it} = \beta_0 T_{it} + \beta_1U_i + \beta_2C_{it} $$

where $y_{it}$ is the outcome, $T_{i}$ is a treatment indicator, $U_i$ is a series of dummies indicating the unit fixed effects, and $C_{it}$ are time-varying confounders. Suppose also that for a subset of units treatment $T_{it}$ is not time-varying but confounders $C_{it}$ are. I would like to estimate $\beta_0$. Is there any benefit in including these units in the regression?